Calculation of x-axis values in a bar plot
I use the following code to create a bar plot:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

products = ['mouse','keyboard','antivirus','scanner','pendrive','battery','mobile']
price = [500, 1200, 550, 4500, 3500, 1500, 2500]
plt.title('Scene-1')
q = plt.bar(products, price)

for b in q:
    val = b.get_height()
    plt.text(b.get_x() + b.get_width()/2, val, round(val, 2), ha= 'center', va= 'bottom')
    print(b)
    print('b.get_x()', '\n', b.get_x())

plt.show()

My question is: how are the x-values returned by b.get_x(), such as -0.4, 0.6, 1.6, 2.6, 3.6, 4.6, 5.6, calculated? And how do these values relate to the positions of the bars on the x-axis in the plot?

When you pass a list of strings to plt.bar for x, the function uses a sequential integer range to determine the positions of the bars on the x-axis, i.e., range(len(products)). With the default settings of width=0.8 and align='center', the integers 0, 1, etc. represent the center of the bars with 0.4 units extending on either side (width/2).
Note that Rectangle.get_x returns the left coordinate of the rectangle. Therefore, the values returned by b.get_x will be:
np.arange(7) - (0.8/2)

array([-0.4,  0.6,  1.6,  2.6,  3.6,  4.6,  5.6])

In your code, you are then adding (0.8/2) (half of the width) to these values again to get the center of the bars, using Rectangle.get_width.
Realizing this, you could in principle also write the following to achieve the same result:
q = plt.bar(products, price)

for x, y in zip(range(len(products)), price):
    plt.text(x=x, y=y, s=round(y, 2), ha='center', va='bottom')
    
locs = plt.gca().get_xticks()
plt.show()

Check with plt.gca and Axes.get_xticks:
print(locs)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Plot:


Note that there exist the function bar_label that handles this for you:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

products = ["mouse", "keyboard", "antivirus", "scanner", "pendrive", "battery", "mobile"]
price = [500, 1200, 550, 4500, 3500, 1500, 2500]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_title("Scene-1")
q = ax.bar(products, price)
ax.bar_label(q)

fig.show()

